# How to hide column if no choices are selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, choice-field, column-formatting

From SharePoint Online, I have a multi-choice column. If the user does not pick any of the choices, how can I set a conditional formula to hide the column.

I tried the following, but it does not work yet:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional formulas in SharePoint online modern experience does **not** support **Multiple choice column**.

**Reference**: [Supported column types in conditional show or hide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#supported-column-types-in-conditional-show-or-hide)

Comment: what if the column is of "hyperlink or picture".  If it has no value (no picture), how do we hide it? I didn't see that on the list of unsupported...

Comment: "Hyperlink or Picture" column is supported. Can you please ask a new question for this? I can add more details and formula specific to that question?